# How to Promise.all multiple arrays of mongoose document inserts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, foreign-keys

I'm trying to insert documents into MongoDB using their Mongoose models, and I'd like to use promises. Since this data originates from an MSSQL database, the documents in each set have foreign key relationships with the documents in other sets.

Here is the example code:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Make = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/make-model'));
const Nameplate = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/nameplate-model'));
const Vehicle = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/vehicle-model'));

const { makes, nameplates, vehicles } = require('./sqlExport.json');

const logErr = (err) => console.error(err);

Promise.resolve(
  mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase()
)
.then(() => (
  Promise.all(
    makes.map(make => (
      Make.create(make).then(makeRes => console.log(`Created make ${makeRes}`))
    ))
  )),
  logErr
)
.then(() => (
  Promise.all(
    nameplates.map(nameplate => {
      const { sqlMakeId, sqlModelId, sqlSubModelId } = nameplate;
      return Make.find({ sqlMakeId })
        .then(makeRes => {
          if (makeRes.length !== 1) throw new Error(`duplicate or non-existent key for make.sqlMakeId: ${sqlMakeId}`);
          const finalNameplate = Object.assign({}, nameplate, { mongoMakeId: makeRes[0]._id });
          return Nameplate.create(finalNameplate);
        })
        .then(nameplateRes => {
          console.log(`Created nameplate ${nameplateRes}`);
        });
    })
  )),
  logErr
)
.then(() => (
  Promise.all(
    vehicles.map(vehicle => {
      const { sqlVehicleId, sqlMakeId, sqlSubModelId } = vehicle;
      const extraParams = {};
      return Make.find({ sqlMakeId })
        .then(makeRes => {
          if (makeRes.length !== 1) throw new Error(`duplicate or non-existent key for make.sqlMakeId: ${sqlMakeId}`);
          extraParams.mongoMakeId = makeRes[0]._id;
          return Nameplate.find({ sqlSubModelId });
        })
        .then(nameplateRes => {
          if (makeRes.length !== 1) throw new Error(`duplicate or non-existent key for nameplate.sqlSubModelId: ${sqlSubModelId}`);
          extraParams.mongoNameplateId = nameplateRes[0]._id;
          const finalVehicle = Object.assign({}, vehicle, extraParams);
          return Vehicle.create(finalVehicle);
        })
        .then(vehicleRes => {
          console.log(`Created vehicle ${vehicleRes}`);
        });
    })
  )),
  logErr
)
.catch(logErr);
```

The problem is that sometimes the vehicle inserts all run before any of the nameplate inserts, and thus can't find the correct document _id for mongoNameplateId.

The full code is here: https://gist.github.com/jeremyjs/1d5509350d3cae69d0e83f1d6478eeb2

Comment: looks like it should work to me. it would help if you could strip the code down to barebones to make debugging easier. One thing I like to do is replace all of your async calls with setTimeout calls that resolve a promise after a second or so and print a message of what they are replacing i.e. `console.log("Make.find('blah')")`

Comment: `Nameplate` and `Vehicle` APIs are promisified but there's no evidence of promisified methods being called. Should `Nameplate.create()` be `Nameplate.createAsync()`, and `Vehicle.create()` be `Vehicle.createAsync()`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 good call. I have never used bluebird, but looking at the docs it states `Note that the original methods on the object are not overwritten but new methods are created with the Async-suffix. For example, if you promisifyAll the node.js fs object use fs.statAsync to call the promisified stat method.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by adding this line below my mongoose and bluebird require statements:

`mongoose.Promise = Promise;`

Documentation here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

In that case the `Promise.promisifyAll` pattern from bluebird was not needed.

Comment: Nice and simple, but if that works then it seems likely that the default `mpromise` would also work. Have you tried with neither Bluebird nor that `mongoose.Promise = Promise` line?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Indeed it does work with mpromise, but Bluebird is more performant than mpromise.

Comment: With typescript I had to put it that way: `(<any>mongoose).Promise = Promise;`